# Adjust border radius smoothly

Tags: html, css

I don't know how to exactly explain this issue,please refer the image to understand the problem. I want The border radius to be smooth i.e. the pixels of border should not get break like given in this image.If it is the way it is?? or Is there any alternative to this problem?
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGpBU.png)

```
<footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="copyright pull-left item_left">© 2017 Uniqueness. All rights reserved.</p>
            <ul class="pull-right social-links text-center item_right">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="mailto:info@unqsbh.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
                <!-- <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-behance"></i></a></li> -->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

I've applied style as given below

```
.footer {
  background-color: #141414;
  border-top: 1px solid #2c2c2c;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 25px 0;
}
.footer .copyright {
  margin: 4px 0 0;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.pull-left {
  float: left !important;
}
.footer .social-links {
  margin: 0;
}
.social-links {
  margin-top: 17px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
}
.pull-right {
  float: right !important;
}
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
.footer .social-links li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
.social-links li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.footer .social-links li a {
  border: 1PX solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 35px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 36px;
}
.logo{
  margin-top: 8px;  
}
.social-links li a {
  display: block;
  height: 42px;
  width: 42px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Your example code doesnt work :) https://jsfiddle.net/kzj504ok/

Comment: @MihanEntalpo OP is also using a library. I'm guessing font-awesome for icon.

Comment: Can you post the rest of the style? your code is a bit broken without it.

Comment: The borders/circles seem fine to me, it might be your screen-resolution that is not high enough to show the circles perfectly smooth. It looks good on my retina-display --> here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/eLf54cbm/

Comment: I've posted rest of the style..

Comment: @Zeronull It it still not smooth..it's not resolution issue

Comment: Sounds like sub-pixel rounding and anti-aliasing. Not much you can do about it.